# SharePoint 2010 Workflow: SPContext.Current.Web.URL returning Object reference not set error

Tags: workflow, development, url, c-sharp

I have a workflow that I have created for an SP 2010 site that does a basic approval process.  In the workflow I have a couple of methods that create an email that is sent out to first the approving manager and then to the office that is processing the form.  Both of these emails contain a link, and I am building the link using html in email body.  The issue I am having is that each time the workflow runs, I get an error when these emails are being created.  After some troubleshooting it seems that my error happens when the link is being built.  Here is an example of what is happening:

```
TravelEmail.Body = "Halito,<br /><p>A new Travel Authorization Form has been submitted by " + workflowProperties.Web.EnsureUser(authForm["Requestor"].ToString().Split('#').ElementAt(1)).Name +
                    " on " + Convert.ToDateTime(authForm["Created"].ToString()).ToShortDateString() + " and was approved by " + workflowProperties.Web.EnsureUser(authForm["Requestor's Manager/Approver"].ToString().Split('#').ElementAt(1)).Name +
                    " on " + Convert.ToDateTime(authForm["Manager's Approval Date"].ToString()).ToShortDateString() + ", and is ready to be processed.  Please " +
                    @"<a href=""" + SPContext.Current.Web.Url+ @"/SitePages/Travel/TravelAuthAdmin.aspx"">click here</a> to review the Travel Authorization Form.</p><p>Yakoke!</p>";
```

Everytime I run this workflow, an exception is thrown at the point where the email body is being formed.  I verified that it was SPContext.Current.Web.URL that was causing the issue by removing that line from both email methods and seeing that the workflow processed correctly.

That being said, what could be my issue?  Also, if I can't use SPContext.Current.Web.URL, how can I get the correct url for my site based on where the workflow is running from (development or test)?